# PDFNet Resize annot Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdftron, pdfnet

Have anyone worked using PDFNet where the annot needs to be resized?
For simplicity, currently i set the text of the annot using

```
annot.setContents(text)
annot.refreshAppearance()
pdfView.update()
```

However, if the text is too long where it exceeds the annot's width, it cant be resized and the text will be trimmed as the annot's width isnt wide enough. I checked the documentation and it seems there is a resize function, however the parameter it is taking isn't clear. Anyone with knowledge on this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you creating the (free-text) annotations? If you are using a `PTToolManager` and creating the annotations with `PTFreeTextCreate` tool class, then you can enable auto-resize for free-text annotations with [`toolManager.isAutoResizeFreeTextEnabled = true`](https://www.pdftron.com/api/ios/Classes/PTToolManager.html#/c:objc(cs)PTToolManager(py)autoResizeFreeTextEnabled)

Using the `PTDocumentController` class for viewing and annotating documents is highly recommended if possible, otherwise a `PTPDFViewCtrl` and `PTToolManager` should be used.

The `PTAnnot.resize()` function is used to set the PDF page rect of the annotation, preserving (ie. scaling) the annotation's appearance to fill its new rect.

Auto-resizing a free-text annotation without a `PTToolManager` would require calculating (yourself) the size of the text. The `PTToolManager` API approach is recommended.